# How to make symbol to be larger?

Tags: equations, subequations

I have an equation, but I want to make a particular symbol inside the math equation be larger.

For instance:

`$$f(x) = \large{X} * y^2$$`.

I want to make `X` to be super large. Any thought?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The  `relsize` package defines, among other commands, `\mathlarger`.

Comment: Do you mean like a summation sign?

Comment: Please define what you understand "super large" to mean.

Comment: stand out from the rest of text in the equation

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there has been no activity since this question was asked, and it is likely the OP has not returned to see comments.

Answer (score 1):

`relsize` package will do as mentioned by Bernard. Using multiples of `\mathlarger` might do the job in your case.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}

$$f(x) = X \times y^2$$

$$f(x) = \mathlarger{X} \times y^2$$

$$f(x) = \mathlarger{\mathlarger{X}} \times y^2$$

$$f(x) = \mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{X}}} \times y^2$$

$$f(x) = \mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{X}}} \mathlarger{\mathlarger{\times}}  y^2$$

%increasing spacing after \times 
$$f(x) = \mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{X}}} \mathlarger{\mathlarger{\times}} \,  y^2$$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Good thinking to nest the command!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Bernard's comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
% https://ctan.org/pkg/relsize
\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{mathtools}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549401
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    f(x) &= x \cdot y^2\\
    f(x) &= \mathlarger{x} \cdot y^2\\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

*(Taken from the `relsize` manual.)*